# regular expression to extract sections

Tags: regex, python-2.7

My string looks like :

```
[abc]
line_one xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
line_two xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[pqr]
line_four xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
line_five xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[xyz]
line_six  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
line_seven  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I am trying to fetch these lines section wise. tried below regular expressions but no luck.

```
result = re.compile(r'(\[.+\])')
details = result.findall(string)
```

with this i am getting section names, then i tried :

```
result = re.compile(r'(\[.+\]((\n)(.+))+)')
```

Any suggestion??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(\[[^\]]*\][^\[]+)(?:\s|$)
```

Try this.See demo.This will give you the lines section wise.

http://regex101.com/r/mP1wO4/1

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(\[[^\]]*\][^\[]+)(?:\s|$)')
test_str = u"[abc]\nline_one xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\nline_two xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n[pqr]\nline_four xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\nline_five xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n[xyz]\nline_six xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\nline_seven xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Comment: it captures also the newline character which was just before to `[]` block.

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.findall` function. You need to include `\n` inside the positive lookahead , so that it won't newline character which was present just before to the `[]` block.

```
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?s)(?:^|\n)(\[[^\]]*\].*?)(?=\n\[[^\]]*\]|$)', s)
>>> m
['[abc]\nline_one xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\nline_two xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', '[pqr]\nline_four xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\nline_five xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', '[xyz]\nline_six  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\nline_seven  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx']
>>> for i in m:
    print(i)


[abc]
line_one xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
line_two xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[pqr]
line_four xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
line_five xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[xyz]
line_six  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
line_seven  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

With split:

```
re.split(r'\n*(?=\[)', s)
```

or

```
re.split(r'(?m)\n*^(?=\[)', s)
```